# Imagick doesn't work in php

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I have a problem. I have installed Image Imagick software, this file:

> ImageMagick-6.8.4-6-Q16-x86-dll.exe

And my php code goes like this:

```
<?php
    $gume = 'svg/EC_tyre_label.svg';
    $im = new Imagick();
    $svg = file_get_contents($gume);

    $im->readImageBlob($svg);
    /*png settings*/
    $im->setImageFormat("png24");
    $im->writeImage('svg/EC_tyre_label.png');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();


?>
<body>
<img src="svg/EC_tyre_label.png" />
</body>
```

My version of php is 5.3.8 and i am using xampp version 1.7.7.
When i open it in the browser, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SVG_antonio\index.php on line 9

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?? Cheers.

Comment: Did you enable ImageMagick in the configuration and restart Xampp (Apache)?

Comment: http://www.zoharbabin.com/5-steps-to-get-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-7-3

Comment: @danielrsmith i have followed those steps but now i can't start xampp apache i get this error:
PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with bulid ID= API20090626,TS,VC6
PHP compiled with build ID = API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match

Answer (score 2):

Is "Imagick" listed as extension, when you call phpinfo() ?!
That's something you need to make sure first, before trying to create any imagick instance.

If it *is* listed as extension, make sure you are not within some namespace, being the reason why plain "imagick" cannot be found.

Try (pay attention to the backslash!):

```
$im = new \Imagick();
```

EDIT:
If it is *not* listed, try the non-thread safe version, and always make sure your extension path within php.ini is set correctly. You might need absolute path-values and use "/" instead of "\" or the other way round for extension-dll-paths.

I cannot post screen captures due to my low reputation, but have google search for images with "phpinfo imagick", you'll find screenshots of how the phpinfo-section looks, if imagick was loaded successfully.

Comment: I have already tested with phpinfo() and it says that in section Apache Environment under path C:\ImageMagick-6.8.4-Q16...and i set the backflash like you said put still the same error...

Comment: There it says.. what !? It needs to be listed as an extension like shown in this picture (i updated my answer, pls look there).

Comment: i didn't understand you where I need to put the "\" or "/" , if mean it in my 'php' code i have tried it already, didn't helped...and i have tried it with non-thread safe version, still same error...

Comment: You need to make clear to us, if imagick is successfully loaded as extension or not. Please tell us, if there is that "big" section called "imagick" when you call phpinfo(). You did not answer that question. Have google search for images with "phpinfo imagick", you'll find screenshots of how the phpinfo-section looks, if imagick was loaded successfully. Without knowing, there's no chance to help, because we don't know where to start (php environment or your plain code being wrong).

Comment: sorry i forgot to write that, in the phpinfo() imagick isn't loaded, sorry again.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on that website, which offers the windows builds ?! "In order to get things running you should add the ImageMagick DLL directory into PATH, add the imagick extension to php.ini and things should be running. At least hopefully." Which version of dll did you try ?! Maybe another XAMP package helps, if you cannot get the binaries to work with that php installation. I run imagick on windows/iis, so I have no experience setting in up for XAMP and Apache. I had issues and tried around too, just to let you know, you're not alone.. o)

Comment: yes i followed the instructions. The first time when I wanted to install imagick I had installed xampp version 1.7.7, but now I have 1.8.1 with php 5.4.7. I had the same problem on both versions. Some times I get the error: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library C:/.../php_imagick_ts.dll - The specified prodecure could not be found." I don't get it i writted in the php.ini file extension=php_imagick_ts.dll or extension=/adding the path/php_imagick_ts.dll and get still the same error.Some times i hate programming because of this bullsh*t.

Answer (score 0):

Download ImageMagick compiled for PHP5.3 with Visual C++ 9 - you will need the TS (thread safe versions).  Here is another site that might have the correct binaries for you:

http://valokuva.org/?page_id=50

Comment: i have tried that solution 3,4 times but I still get the same error.

Comment: That url is down is there a mirror?